# Count night each room in ordinal number

Tags: php, mysql, date, count, ordinal

I want to count day with it's position (likely an ordinal but just a position of day) for each room type. For example, I have two types of room which is booked the exact same period (from `2012-11-30` to `2012-12-06`). And I need each day of each room type counted.

Please have a look at the table below.

[image]

I need a column `day` to run a day position. Basicly I wrote mySQL as:

```
SELECT ????? , booking_customer.bkcus_date AS DATE, villas_db.v_name AS vname, booking_customer.bkcus_rate AS cost
FROM booking_customer
INNER JOIN villas_db ON booking_customer.bkcus_vid = villas_db.v_id
WHERE booking_customer.bkcus_sid =  '<sid>'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Where `?????` is a needed code to run such a number. So could you guy please suggest me if there's a better way to get this done - PHP for example.

Regards,

Comment: why not generate it in your client? it's possible in sql, but it's ugly. by far easier to do in PHP

Comment: @MarcB pleas shoe me how. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, as a very ugly two-query SQL hack:

```
SET @cntr = null, @prev=null;

SELECT IF((@prev <> vname) or (@prev is null)),
    @cntr := 1, @cntr := @cntr + 1) AS day,
    @prev := vname,
    etc...
FROM ...
...
```

This will only work if your main the sorting order you have in your screencap. if you start changing the sort order, you'll get a whole different set of numbers

Comment: From your code. The result is only show up for the vname=V2 only. V1 is displayes as NULL. It close, this is what I really want.

Comment: It's work now.

`SELECT IF( (
(
@prev <> villas_db.v_name
)
OR (
@prev IS NULL
) ) , @cntr :=1, @cntr := @cntr +1
) AS 
DAY , @prev := villas_db.v_name, booking_customer.bkcus_date AS DATE, villas_db.v_name AS vname, booking_customer.bkcus_rate AS cost
FROM booking_customer
INNER JOIN villas_db ON booking_customer.bkcus_vid = villas_db.v_id
WHERE booking_customer.bkcus_sid =  '<sid>'
LIMIT 0 , 30`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a SQL solution here you go:
This does not require additional statement like `SET @counter = 0;`

//edited second time

```
SELECT IF((@counter := @counter + 1) < 8, @counter, @counter := 1 ) AS day,
    booking_customer.bkcus_date AS DATE, 
    villas_db.v_name AS vname, 
    booking_customer.bkcus_rate AS cost
FROM (SELECT @counter:=0) AS c, booking_customer
INNER JOIN villas_db ON booking_customer.bkcus_vid = villas_db.v_id
WHERE booking_customer.bkcus_sid =  '<sid>'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: I don't want a week day I just only want to count each day of the room type is booked. 30Nov2012 is the 1st, 1Dec2012 is the 2nd...6Dec2012 is the 7th of the booking. Your code is brilliant but it is a bit far from my expectation.

Comment: @Wilf I have totally misunderstood you there, sorry, this should be better... oh, someone else already made that solution :(

Comment: your solution is also interesting. May I have a question on it? What is '8' comes from? May I guess - a total of days+1???

Comment: according to your code why mySQL keep saying : `#1054 - Unknown column 'booking_customer.bkcus_vid' in 'on clause'` ? Despite it existed.

Comment: @Wilf Yeah, this is because LEFT JOIN (I've tested my query on single table, not joined), order of tables in FROM clause has to be reversed: `FROM (SELECT @counter:=0) AS c, booking_customer`... The 8 is limiter, I could have written it a bit differently with <= 7

Comment: Ivan, your updated code is nearly work. But there's a double 1 on the first two days of V2. Why is that? Please explain I'd rather want to learn.

Comment: These errors of mine are getting awfully annoying today :) ... I have reseted @counter to 0 then added 1, and I have just needed to reset it to 1... this should work now

Comment: Ivan, Whatever! Your code is awesome, So to Marc B. You both appreciated.